# iOS: How to implement MoPub native ad page with AFKPageFlipper every fifth page

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, mopub

I'd like to implement MoPub ads within AFKPageFlipper so that an ad which is a UIView appears every five pages.

The method that returns the view for AFKPAgeFlipper looks like this:

```
- (UIView *) viewForPage:(NSInteger) pagenr inFlipper:(AFKPageFlipper *) pageFlipper
```

The code I have that displays my regular view is:

```
    Page* page = self.episode.pages[pagenr - 1];

page.episode = self.episode;
ReaderPageView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReaderPageView"
                                                      owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
view.page = page;
if(pagenr == self.startPage && !self.alreadyStarted) {
    self.alreadyStarted = YES;
    [view setupFirstPage];
} else {
    [self manageCacheHandler:pagenr];
}
```

The code for displaying an ad is:

```
NativeFlipperAdPageView* view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NativeFlipperAdPageView"
                                                               owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];

if ((self.nativeAd != nil)) {

    UIView *view = [self.nativeAd retrieveAdViewWithError:nil];
    [self.viewForContent addSubview:view];
    NSLog(@"Ad Subview added!");
    return view;
}
return view;
```

However, I don't know how to implement both pieces inside viewForPage method so that an ad is displayed every fifth time and then continue with regular pages. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Just set a counter variable at global level which gets incremented every time the page is changed. And then check if `pageChangeCount % 5 == 0`. If true display the ad, else not.